# How to align the h1 tag and the image tag on one line adjacently?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have problems with trying to align the image and the h1 tag together on one line. I tried display: inline and inline-block they didn't work and only made the container of the two. I added the width to 100% on the section and still nothing. Float doesn't work either and if it did, it screws up the alignment of the page. What am I doing wrong? Check my full source code here: http://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/bkmyv/

HTML

```
<section>
    <img id="me" src="assets/img/pose1.jpg" alt="A photo of me." />
    <h1>FOLLOW ME ON...</h1>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section{
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
}
h1{
font-weight:bold;
font-size:40px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#FFB405;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `float:left;` to `#me` and `float:right;` to `h1` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/AH7UN/)

```
#me{
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  float: left;
}
h1{
  display:inline-block;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:40px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#FFB405;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: got a warning: inline-block is ignored due to float.

Answer (score 5):

This is because images as displayed as block elements by default, so they occupy a whole line.

Change your image to have a `display: inline-block;` as you did with your `h1` element.

```
h1, img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here' a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ps2ms/

Answer (score 0):

Just give the img in the section a float: left.